# Probability that difference between demand for two skills in a population sample is due to chance

Tags: statistical-significance, independence, population

I am trying to measure the demand for two skills in group of companies that are hiring software developers. One skill might be e.g. Java and the other e.g. C++. If out of 100 companies, 30 report they are looking for Java developers and 20 report they are looking for C++ developers, there are 3 possible scenarios:

1. Java is more in demand than C++ in the total population (all companies in the world).
2. C++ is more in demand than Java in the total population.
3. The two languages are (roughly) equally in demand.

How would I calculate statistically the probability that 1, 2 or 3 is the true situation? I guess this is similar to the problem political pollsters face in deciding whether differences in voting intentions for two candidates are due to chance. I am assuming that demand for the two skills is not correlated.

Comment: Your null hypothesis for case 1: demand for the two languages is equal. If you can show this false, you know one language (and which language) is more popular. Null hypothesis for case 2: demand for the two languages is unequal. Note that it's quite possible you won't be able to reject either hypothesis, which means there is insufficient data to determine which of the 3 choices is correct.

Comment: Upon reflection, I'm not sure whether my question makes sense. Really what I want to know is the confidence interval around the demand for each specific language. I assumed binomial distribution for the demand and used Adjusted Wald to calculate the confidence intervals, which look plausible to me.

Comment: Nonetheless, I'd be interested in insights on how to calculate the probability that one language is more popular than another given these confidence intervals.

Comment: http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda353.htm http://www.real-statistics.com/students-t-distribution/two-sample-t-test-equal-variances/ http://www.cliffsnotes.com/math/statistics/univariate-inferential-tests/two-sample-t-test-for-comparing-two-means may or may not be helpful. I've become obsessed with this problem and may post my own solution anyway.